# HTML5 / JavaScript Drag and Drop Cart

Tags: javascript, html

Hoping someone can help me.

Checked other, similar questions on this forum but still can't solve this problem.

Trying to create a simple shopping cart using HTML5 (Drag and Drop) and JavaScript. I've copied most of the code below from an online tutorial (code was open source and free to use). I want to extend the code so that, as items are dragged into cart area, the total cost of all items in the cart is displayed. This total would be updated as more items are added.

Also, I'm trying to update the code so that a user can purchase more than one of any item and am trying to get the display to also show quantity of each item in cart.

I've added an updateCart() function but I'm confused as to how to get it working properly (obviously it's not functioning as intended). Since the drag and drop from original code is working the problem must be in my updateCart function.

I've added ' data-price' and 'data-quantity' attributes to the li tags of shop items. I've tried to get total price to display but haven't looked at item quantity yet.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Drag and drop in HTML 5, demonstration with a shop</title>
  <style>
  body {
  padding:32px;
  }
 .shop {
 border-radius:6px;
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 }

 .shop li{
 display:inline;
 }
 .cart {
  border: 4px solid #0066FF;
  border-radius:6px;
  min-height:128px;
  display:block;
  }
 .product {
 border:3px solid white;
 }
.product:hover {
 border:3px solid red;
 cursor:move;
 }
.itemchoosen {
this.style.opacity = 0.5;
this.style.border = "2px solid red";
 }
.itemblurred {
this.style.border = none;
}

#cartArea {
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
border: 1px dotted #999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >

<fieldset><legend>The shop</legend>

<ul id="shop" class="shop">
<li data-price="30.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="chair" src="images/chair.jpg"     width="96" height="96"></li>
<li data-price="250.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="monitor" src="images/screen.jpg" width="96" height="96"></li>
<li data-price="80.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="bag" src="images/bag.jpg" width="96" height="96"></li>
<li data-price="350.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="transat" src="images/transat.jpg" width="96" height="96"></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="mycart" class="cart"><legend>My cart</legend>
<div id="cartArea"></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="mycart" class="cart"><legend>Total</legend>
<p id="the_sub_total"></p>
<p id="the_total"></p>
</fieldset>

<script>
var cartArea = document.querySelector('#cartArea'); 

var prods = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
for(var i = 0; i < prods.length; i++)
{
prods[i].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // optional with images
prods[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function(evnt) {
    this.className = 'itemchoosen';
    evnt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    evnt.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.id);
    return false;  
}, false);
}   


cartArea.addEventListener('dragover', function(evnt) {
    if (evnt.preventDefault) evnt.preventDefault();
    evnt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    return false;   
}, false);

cartArea.addEventListener('dragenter', function(evnt) {
    return false;   
}, false);

cartArea.addEventListener('dragleave', function(evnt) {
    return false;
}, false);

cartArea.addEventListener('drop', function(evnt) {
if (evnt.stopPropagation) evnt.stopPropagation();
var id = evnt.dataTransfer.getData('text');     
var theitem = document.getElementById(id);  
//theitem.parentNode.removeChild(el);   
theitem.className='itemblurred';
var y  = document.createElement('img');
y.src = theitem.src;
cartArea.appendChild(y);
evnt.preventDefault(); // for Firefox

updateCart();

return false;

}, false);

function updateCart(){
var total = 0.0;
var cart_items = document.querySelectorAll("#shop li")
for (var i = 0; i < cart_items.length; i++) {
    var cart_item = cart_items[i];
    var quantity = cart_item.getAttribute('data-quantity');
    var price = cart_item.getAttribute('data-price');
    var sub_total = parseFloat(quantity * parseFloat(price));
    //document.querySelectorAll("#the_sub_total")[0].innerHTML = " = " + sub_total.toFixed(2);
    total += sub_total;
}

document.querySelectorAll("#the_total")[0].innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Drag and drop in HTML 5, demonstration with a shop</title>
  <style>
  body {
  padding:32px;
  }
 .shop {
 border-radius:6px;
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 }

 .shop li{
 display:inline;
 }
 .cart {
  border: 4px solid #0066FF;
  border-radius:6px;
  min-height:128px;
  display:block;
  }
 .product {
 border:3px solid white;
 }
.product:hover {
 border:3px solid red;
 cursor:move;
 }
.itemchoosen {
this.style.opacity = 0.5;
this.style.border = "2px solid red";
 }
.itemblurred {
this.style.border = none;
}

#cartArea {
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
border: 1px dotted #999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >

<fieldset><legend>The shop</legend>

<ul id="shop" class="shop">
<li data-price="30.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="chair" src="images/chair.jpg"     width="96" height="96"></li>
<li data-price="250.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="monitor" src="images/screen.jpg" width="96" height="96"></li>
<li data-price="80.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="bag" src="images/bag.jpg" width="96" height="96"></li>
<li data-price="350.00" data-quantity="1"><img class="product" id="transat" src="images/transat.jpg" width="96" height="96"></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="mycart" class="cart"><legend>My cart</legend>
<div id="cartArea"></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="mycart" class="cart"><legend>Total</legend>
<p id="the_sub_total"></p>
<p id="the_total"></p>
</fieldset>

<script>
var total = 0.0;
var cartArea = document.querySelector('#cartArea'); 

var prods = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
for(var i = 0; i < prods.length; i++)
{
prods[i].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // optional with images
prods[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function(evnt) {
    this.className = 'itemchoosen';
    evnt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    evnt.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.id);
    return false;  
}, false);
}   


cartArea.addEventListener('dragover', function(evnt) {
    if (evnt.preventDefault) evnt.preventDefault();
    evnt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    return false;   
}, false);

cartArea.addEventListener('dragenter', function(evnt) {
    return false;   
}, false);

cartArea.addEventListener('dragleave', function(evnt) {
    return false;
}, false);

cartArea.addEventListener('drop', function(evnt) {
if (evnt.stopPropagation) evnt.stopPropagation();

var id = evnt.dataTransfer.getData('text');     
var theitem = document.getElementById(id);  
console.log(theitem.parentNode.attributes); 
var quantity=theitem.parentNode.attributes['data-quantity'].value;
var price = theitem.parentNode.attributes['data-price'].value;
console.log(price);
theitem.className='itemblurred';
var y  = document.createElement('img');
y.src = theitem.src;
cartArea.appendChild(y);
evnt.preventDefault(); // for Firefox

updateCart(quantity,price);

return false;

}, false);

function updateCart(quantity,price){
    var sub_total = parseFloat(quantity * parseFloat(price));
    total = total+sub_total;
    document.getElementById('total').value= total;
document.querySelectorAll("#the_total")[0].innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @Mekong try this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Code:**

You are running a loop in **updateCart()** to first get the price of all the items and then check what all items are there in the cart, instead you can send the price as the parameter in the **updateCart()** function, as you are already getting the element which is recently dropped in the `cartArea.addEventListener('drop', function(evnt)`.

You can add a scroll to the **cartArea** if you want.

But I am not getting why you have used `sub_total` in this, if you want to show the item price below the item image, then there is no need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Drag and drop in HTML 5, demonstration with a shop</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding:32px;
        }
        .shop {
            border-radius:6px;
            list-style-type:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        .shop li{
            display: inline-table;
        }
        .cart {
            border: 4px solid #0066FF;
            border-radius:6px;
            min-height:128px;
            display:block;
            padding: 20px 10px;
        }
        .product {
            border:3px solid white;
        }
        .product:hover {
            border:3px solid red;
            cursor:move;
        }
        .itemchoosen {
            this.style.opacity = 0.5;
            this.style.border = "2px solid red";
        }
        .itemblurred {
            this.style.border = none;
        }
        #cartArea {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        #cartArea img {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 2%;
        }
        .itemPrice {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >
    <fieldset><legend>The shop</legend>
        <ul id="shop" class="shop">
            <li><img class="product" id="chair" src="images/chair.jpg" width="96" height="96" data-price="30.00" data-quantity="1"></li>
            <li><img class="product" id="monitor" src="images/screen.jpg" width="96" height="96" data-price="250.00" data-quantity="1"></li>
            <li><img class="product" id="bag" src="images/bag.jpg" width="96" height="96" data-price="80.00" data-quantity="1"></li>
            <li><img class="product" id="transat" src="images/transat.jpg" width="96" height="96" data-price="350.00" data-quantity="1"></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="mycart" class="cart">
        <legend>My cart</legend>
        <div id="cartArea"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="mycart" class="cart">
        <legend>Total</legend>
        <p id="the_sub_total"></p>
        <p id="the_total">0</p>
    </fieldset>
    <script>
        var cartArea = document.querySelector('#cartArea'); 
        var prods = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
        var itemPriceElement;
        for(var i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {
            itemPriceElement = document.createElement("span");
            itemPriceElement.className = "itemPrice";
            itemPriceElement.innerHTML = prods[i].getAttribute("data-price");
            prods[i].parentNode.insertBefore(itemPriceElement, prods[i].nextSibling);
            prods[i].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // optional with images
            prods[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function(evnt) {
                //this.className = 'itemchoosen';
                this.classList.add('itemchoosen');
                evnt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
                evnt.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.id);
                return false;  
            }, false);
        }   
        cartArea.addEventListener('dragover', function(evnt) {
            if (evnt.preventDefault) evnt.preventDefault();
            evnt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
            return false;   
        }, false);
        cartArea.addEventListener('dragenter', function(evnt) {
            return false;   
        }, false);
        cartArea.addEventListener('dragleave', function(evnt) {
            return false;
        }, false);
        cartArea.addEventListener('drop', function(evnt) {
            if (evnt.stopPropagation) evnt.stopPropagation();
            var id = evnt.dataTransfer.getData('text');     
            var theitem = document.getElementById(id); 
            //theitem.parentNode.removeChild(el);   
            //theitem.className='itemblurred';
            theitem.classList.add('itemblurred');
            var y  = document.createElement('img');
            y.src = theitem.src;
            cartArea.appendChild(y);
            evnt.preventDefault(); // for Firefox
            updateCart(theitem.getAttribute("data-price"));
            return false;
        }, false);
        function updateCart(price){
            var the_total = document.getElementById("the_total").innerHTML;
            the_total = parseInt(the_total);
            the_total = the_total + parseInt(price);
            document.getElementById("the_total").innerHTML = the_total;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```